# How to build graph in javascript?

Tags: javascript, graph

I was building a graph in JavaScript and I met this problem.

The output is not what I want.

What I know about graphs is between each node has edge and
this `adjacentList`'s goal is to show the edge and make a connection to the node.

If my code is not complete, please give me a hint to finish it or just fix my code and meet the request.

The output should be:

```
Answer:
0-->1 2
1-->3 2 0
2-->4 1 0
3-->1 4
4-->3 2 5
5-->4 6
6-->5
```

Here is my JS:

```js
 class Graph { 
    constructor() { 
    this.numberOfNodes = 0;
    this.adjacentList = {
    }; 
  } 
  addVertex(node)  { 
    this.adjacentList[node]=[];
    this.numberOfNodes++;
   } 
   addEdge(node1, node2) { 
    this.adjacentList[node1]=[];
    this.adjacentList[node1].push(node2);
   } 
  showConnections() { 
    const allNodes = Object.keys(this.adjacentList); 
    for (let node of allNodes) { 
       let nodeConnections = this.adjacentList[node]; 
       let connections = ""; 
       let vertex;
    for (vertex of nodeConnections) {
        connections += vertex + " ";
      } 
       console.log(node + "-->" + connections); 
      } 
     } 
    } 

    const myGraph = new Graph();
    myGraph.addVertex('0');
    myGraph.addVertex('1');
    myGraph.addVertex('2');
    myGraph.addVertex('3');
    myGraph.addVertex('4');
    myGraph.addVertex('5');
    myGraph.addVertex('6');
    myGraph.addEdge('3', '1'); 
    myGraph.addEdge('3', '4'); 
    myGraph.addEdge('4', '2'); 
    myGraph.addEdge('4', '5'); 
    myGraph.addEdge('1', '2'); 
    myGraph.addEdge('1', '0'); 
    myGraph.addEdge('0', '2'); 
    myGraph.addEdge('6', '5');

    myGraph.showConnections();
```

Comment: Maybe try one of these references: https://www.google.com/search?q=js+graph+structure

Comment: @cat thanks,but i want to use my code to get the output because it's my  homework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
addVertex(node)  { 
  this.adjacentList[node]=[]; <---| 
  this.numberOfNodes++;           |
 }                                |  <-- Do the same task
 addEdge(node1, node2) {          |  
  this.adjacentList[node1]=[];----|
  this.adjacentList[node1].push(node2);
}
```

Then you should remove `this.adjacentList[node1]=[]` from `addEdge` function.
And because your graph is getting data from both sides:

```
[{'1': '3'}, {'3': '2'}] =>  3-->1,2
```

Then you should push the node in 2 ways

```
addEdge(node1, node2) {
  this.adjacentList[node1].push(node2);
  this.adjacentList[node2].push(node1);
}
```

The code should be:

```js
class Graph { 
    constructor() { 
    this.numberOfNodes = 0;
    this.adjacentList = {
    }; 
  } 
  addVertex(node)  { 
    this.adjacentList[node]=[];
    this.numberOfNodes++;
   } 
   addEdge(node1, node2) { 
    // this.adjacentList[node1]=[]; <------------ Remove this line
     this.adjacentList[node1].push(node2);
     this.adjacentList[node2].push(node1); // <-- Add this line
   }
  
  showConnections() { 
    const allNodes = Object.keys(this.adjacentList); 
    for (let node of allNodes) { 
       let nodeConnections = this.adjacentList[node]; 
       let connections = ""; 
       let vertex;
    for (vertex of nodeConnections) {
        connections += vertex + " ";
      } 
       console.log(node + "-->" + connections); 
      } 
     } 
    } 

    const myGraph = new Graph();
    myGraph.addVertex('0');
    myGraph.addVertex('1');
    myGraph.addVertex('2');
    myGraph.addVertex('3');
    myGraph.addVertex('4');
    myGraph.addVertex('5');
    myGraph.addVertex('6');
    myGraph.addEdge('3', '1'); 
    myGraph.addEdge('3', '4'); 
    myGraph.addEdge('4', '2'); 
    myGraph.addEdge('4', '5'); 
    myGraph.addEdge('1', '2'); 
    myGraph.addEdge('1', '0'); 
    myGraph.addEdge('0', '2'); 
    myGraph.addEdge('6', '5');

    myGraph.showConnections();
```

Besides, you should handle the error and take a look at `showConnection` to optimate it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I came up with [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to solve the problem. You can take a look.

```js
function Graph() {
  let nodes = new Map()
  
  this.addVertex = node => {
    if(!nodes.has(node)) nodes.set(node, new Set())
  }
  
  this.addEdge = (node, egde) => {
    if(nodes.has(node) && nodes.has(egde)) {
      nodes.get(node).add(egde)
      nodes.get(egde).add(node)
    }
  }
  
  this.showConnections = () => {
    nodes.forEach((node, index) => console.log(`${index} -> ${[...node]}`) )
  }
}

const myGraph  = new Graph()
    myGraph.addVertex('0');
    myGraph.addVertex('1');
    myGraph.addVertex('2');
    myGraph.addVertex('3');
    myGraph.addVertex('4');
    myGraph.addVertex('5');
    myGraph.addVertex('6');
    myGraph.addEdge('3', '1'); 
    myGraph.addEdge('3', '4'); 
    myGraph.addEdge('4', '2'); 
    myGraph.addEdge('4', '5'); 
    myGraph.addEdge('1', '2'); 
    myGraph.addEdge('1', '0'); 
    myGraph.addEdge('0', '2'); 
    myGraph.addEdge('6', '5');

myGraph.showConnections();
```

Comment: Thanks,but i want to use my code to get the answer.Is there something i can do in my code?

Comment: It's really hard to understand your code. What `numberOfNodes` is using for? You create `newNode` but didn't use it (in both functions). And the way you're working with array and object is so verbose(`showConnections` function). You should read more about how to work with these objects.

Comment: I posted a new answer for that. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Object `properties` are defined using a semicolon `'` rather than equals `=`. Also, individual properties are separated using comma `,` rather than semi-colon `;`

So your snippet:

```
const newNode={
      this.numberOfNodes = 0;
      this.adjacentList = {
     };
```

should actually be something like:

```
const newNode={
      numberOfNodes : 0,
      adjacentList : {
     };
```

Comment: Fixing all this still gives `node is not defined` because you are referencing `node` inside `addEdge()` where the former is not defined.